# Trying to do Age Validation based on selected value from dropdown list and datepicker in ASP.NET Web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, frontend

I am doing booking web application for a hotel. I have a form where person should enter data for himself and other people. I want to do age validation and make two fields dependable.
1st field: Person should choose if he is adult or children.
2nd field: Date of birth. Here i want the validation to execute. If person entered that he is adult, the validation to check if person is above 18. If entered children, check if person is under 18.

I will post a photo below from the form. I want to do it with javascript/jquery. But i am also open to other suggestions. I am using ASP.NET MVC to built this web app.

The form is in bulgarian. So that is why i wrote in english in snipping tools.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cspty.png)

Comment: do it with javascript/jquery..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This validation isn't necessary. If it is necessary for the user to input the date of birth. Then they shouldn't be required to stipulate whether they are adult by your definition (in this case, over 18).

Instead, you should define it yourself and display the result (adult or child) as a label.

So after they select their date of birth. Read that value with some javascript, find their age by simple subtraction from Javascript's `Date` object using `.now();` or `getFullYear();`. Then display whether they are child or adult as a label dynamically.

This is more of a User Experience issue. Reducing the confusion and human error is the ideal route to take.

If your client insists that the user should be given the freedom of making a selection which fails form validation, then that is another story. You can produce a better solution for this the more time you spend trying to make it user friendly (eg, restrict dates they can pick based on the other form control), but then you would be making the 1 control depend on the other. Where the functionality of 1 is always effected by the value selected in the other.

Comment: Your view of this problem helped me. Instead of doing validation i added javascipt code where based on selected birth date i change the value of person type. Thanks again. I can share my code later, if needed.

Comment: Glad it helped you. Sometimes the solution to the problem is a different approach :)